# Am I blocked from some Tor?

Tags: directory

After successfully using Tor for several months I became unable to access any of the .onions. I've tried reinstalling Tor. It says that its working and I have no trouble connecting to any other sites via Tor. I'm having this problem on three different devices which rules out device settings. I did have a page pop up that said this account has been blocked to prevent DDOS attacks.So my question is who can I contact to get this "block" if thats what it is removed. I've been down for more than a week now and suspest there are a couple of folks out there wondering WTF. I appreciate any ideas, THANKS

Comment: Can you access this hidden service: http://idnxcnkne4qt76tg.onion It is the homepage of the Tor project.

Comment: The question has no activity since January and it is unlikely that this will change. So I close the question.